# Xcode - How to reset: Show only recent files

Tags: xcode

In Xcode 10 (and earlier versions too), you can click the little clock icon in the bottom left of the Navigator (see screenshot). It will show/hide the most recent files you have worked with. I've just learned about this great feature.

How do I reset the filter manually? What resets this automatically? Committing or shutting down Xcode does not seem to reset the list.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data is stored in the `xcuserdata` folder of your `.xcworkspace` or `.xcodeproj` package.

For Project:
Remove `<username>.xcuserdatad` folder content in path `xx.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/` and `xx.xcodeproj/xx.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/`

For Workspace:
Remove `<username>.xcuserdatad` folder content in path `xx.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/`

**NOTE**: You have to close your Xcode first.

Comment: Thanks for the info. There is no setting though that you are aware of right?

Comment: @user1269290 Not that i know of.